# FFMPEG Can Find libx264 in Konsole, but Not in Program?

Tags: java, ffmpeg, java-10

I'm writing a small program to deal with a large video library that was mis-labelled and in the wrong format from a while ago.

I'm using `ProcessBuilder` for the CLI arguments, but found something strange. Konsole can execute the exact same CLI arguments for my conversation task, but the Java process can't.

ffmpeg comes up just fine in the process, but says `Unknown encoder 'libx264'`.

This doesn't happen when I run the command (In the same directory) with Konsole. I even had it return the command that it is executing using `builder.command().stream().forEachOrdered(string -> System.out.print(string + " "));` and ran it in Konsole. It works just fine in Konsole, but not in my Java process.

It gives me `ffmpeg -i VTS_01_1.VOB -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict experimental Cod-4 1.mp4` which runs just fine in Konsole.

Here is the subroutine:

```
//ffmpeg -i VTS_01_1.VOB -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict experimental Test.mp4
            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("ffmpeg", "-i", filePath.getFileName().toString(),
                    "-c:v", "libx264", "-c:a", "aac", "-strict", "experimental", fileName + ".mp4")
                    .directory(filePath.getParent().toFile()).inheritIO();
            Process proc = builder.start();
            proc.waitFor();
            System.out.println("\n\n");
            builder.command().stream().forEachOrdered(string -> System.out.print(string + " "));
```

And the full output of ffmpeg from the Netbeans window:

```
ffmpeg version 4.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
    configuration: 
    libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
    libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
    libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
    libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
    libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
    libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
    libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
  Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.2 : stereo
  Input #0, mpeg, from 'VTS_01_1.VOB':
    Duration: 00:14:44.44, start: 0.233567, bitrate: 9712 kb/s
      Stream #0:0[0x1bf]: Data: dvd_nav_packet
Stream #0:1[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m, top first), 720x480 [SAR 8:9 DAR 4:3], 8000 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
Stream #0:2[0xa0]: Audio: pcm_dvd, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
  Unknown encoder 'libx264'


ffmpeg -i VTS_01_1.VOB -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict experimental Cod-4 1.mp4
```

I'm on Kubuntu 18.04.01 LTS.

**EDIT 0:**  Upon further reflection, this may be due to an unusual startup routine that I do for Netbeans.  I was an early adopter for Netbeans 9 on KDE and have to run it using sudo, or else it simply doesn't run at all.

This may have something to do with it. I just tested it (Same command) + sudo and got the error message that the program was getting about linx264 not being found.

I can't imagine why though.

Comment: Check the path for ffmpeg. The 2nd log indicates that Netbeans is calling a ffmpeg binary without any external library linked.